# Why ES6 has 'find' method as its functionality can be achieved through 'reduce'?

Tags: ecmascript-6, find, reduce

In javascript we encounter a phase where we want to fetch an object from Array of Objects based on key(if we are not working in context of Backbone collection).

The newer version of javascript has method find to accomplish above operation directly.

but it also can be done through reduce method in es5.

Comment: Whis is there `find()` method if there's a `reduce()` method? Why is there a `reduce()` method if you can just loop over the array? Why is there an array if you could just put everything in a byte buffer?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason why `.find()` was introduced is that it's a pretty commonly needed functionality. Take for example following code:

```
let arr = [{id: 1, descriptor: "firstElement"}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 1, descriptor: "lastElement"}];

// find using reduce
let foundItem = arr.reduce((prevItem, item) => item.id === 1 ? item : prevItem, arr); 

// find using find
let foundItem2 = arr.find(item => item.id === 1);

console.log(foundItem); // prints: {id: 1, descriptor: "lastElement"}
console.log(foundItem2); // prints: {id: 1, descriptor: "firstElement"}
```

The code using `.find()` is more concise and easier to read. In addition, `.find()` expresses exactly what you want to do here: "Find the first item that matches the expression", whereas `.reduce()` only expresses "Reduce the array to one item, however that may look". You have to read the expression to determine what the reduce is doing. That's a hassle for common functionalities like finding something.

Another difference: `.find()` stops after the first element is found and returns that first element. The `reduce()` approach does not stop and, as I implemented it, it will return the LAST matching element in the array. If you wanted the first, reduce would look like this:

```
let arr = [{id: 1, descriptor: "firstElement"}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 1, descriptor: "lastElement"}];

let foundItem = arr.reduce((prevItem, item) => prevItem.id === 1 ? prevItem : item.id === 1 ? item : prevItem, arr);
```

Now the reduce gets even more unreadable.